# TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded in puppeteer in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ubuntu, puppeteer, chromium

No issue in windows.. But in production server ubuntu, I'm getting this error after goto function

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    });

        const url: String = login.url;

        const page: any = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36');

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1520,
            height: 800,
            deviceScaleFactor: 1,
            isMobile: false
        });
```

chromium-browser installed, puppeteer installed and some others like libgbm-dev or something

Anyone tell me whats the issue?
If you need any more informations please comment...

Comment: You're probably being detected as a bot and adding the UA isn't enough. Please provide the URL so the code can be executed.

Comment: @ggorlen yes I think this was the issue because other URLs are working perfectly. I used this URL for an automation purpose, so may be they blocked my IP or something like that. Thanks for your reply

Comment: It's a good idea to `console.log(await page.content())` and look at what it says. This usually has an "access denied" message or a captcha and cloudfront is often also somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was running an Ubuntu server with 512MB memory that could not handle running my scripts. I figured this out by writing a simple scraper that visited Google, which worked fine. I then ran my more intensive scrapers, and watched memory usage via `htop`, while they failed to execute and giving me a timeout error.

I upgraded the server two 2gb of memory, and everything worked fine. You might not need to upgrade all the way to 2gb, but I did just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but I think my problem was not this. I noted it in the comments

Comment: Dan's advice worked for me.  While running puppeteer, my server would eventually get to a load average of over 10.0, and the 1GB of physical RAM + 512MB of swap was used up.  The server was barely responsive, but the moment I added 1GB of additional swap, it became responsive again and the timeouts stopped happening.  I didn't even have to restart puppeteer, and my load average is back down to barely over 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer sometimes require lot of time to answer.

in my case: **Puppeteer-19.4.1 Ubuntu-20.04.1 LTS (server) with 1gb RAM**, i solve the issue just **increasing "page.goto" timeout at 2 minutes**.

```
await page.goto(url, {'timeout': 120000});
```